# I need help to transform a datetime in a dataframe, separate data into groups and save in a list or dictionary?

Tags: python, list, datetime, dictionary, data-analysis

I have two data series, with date and time. I need to separate the data that is in minutes within the time range, i.e. how many data are between 1 and 2 hours. But I can not change the data, I have to do it just for the index. Imagine this as an example:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from random import *

# This generates a list of date and time.
dti = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=4, freq='H')

# transform it into a dataframe to be able to access the index.
dt = pd.DataFrame(dti)

# Now a new list with 3 hours of data per second.
dti2 = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=10800, freq='s')

# again a data frame to be able to rotate the indexes.
dt3 = pd.DataFrame(dti2)

# Here I try to make dt3 data between dt1 times.
list = []
for i in range(len(dt)):
    j=0
    while(dt[0][i+1] >= dt3[0][j] >= dt[0][i]):
        list.append(dt3[0][j])
        j=j+1
```

`data = pd.DataFrame(list)` = 3601 rows × 1 columns -> 2018-01-01 00:00:01..2018-01-01 00:01:00

## Expected

I can only create a list between 0 hours and 1 hours, but it does not continue. I thought about creating a dictionary where the key would be a time and the data a list of data between that time, but I don't know how to do it.

## Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f948f57a170d> in <module>
      2 for i in range(len(dt)):
      3     j=0
----> 4     while(dt\[0\]\[i+1\] >= dt3\[0\]\[j\] >= dt\[0\]\[i\]):
      5         list.append(dt3\[0\]\[j\])
      6 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

    KeyError: 4][1][enter image description here][1]
```

## Data Image

[Dt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8OCM.png) [Data Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wyu5.png)  [Darult Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vgz6.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code. ... [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)